# Creating new table while iterating through a queryset in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

This is a newbie question, but despite reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects , I'm not quite sure how to do this. I have an existing table where I would like to iterate through all its records, and save certain info to a second table. I have the following model:

```
class myEmails(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
```

In my view I have:

```
def getMyMessages(request):    

    from django_mailbox.models import Message
    from get_new_emails.models import myEmails
    import re    

    qs = Message.objects.all()
    count = 0
    output = ""
    for i in qs:
        count += 1
        output = output + str(count) + " TEXT: " + i.text + '<br>' + '<br>'    

    return HttpResponse(output)
```

How can I modify my view to save "i.text" to the text field of the 'myEmails' table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new objects and save them to the database afterwards using `save()`:

```
for i in qs:
    obj = myEmails(text=i.text)
    obj.save()
```